# Following official docs of PNPM and failed on Installation

Tags: npm, npm-install, pnpm

**Little Background Story**
I was trying to use pnpm, however upon installation, something went wrong, at first I thought it was corrupted files or something, so I tried to uninstall and install it again, but the same thing happen three times.. So here's what they say from the docs itself.

Directly from the [docs](https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/installation.html),

Via npm: ***Succeed***

```
npm install -g pnpm
```

However, in the next step, something is wrong.. I had no idea why, as I'm still newbie when using NPM.

Once you first installed pnpm, you can upgrade it using pnpm:

```
pnpm install -g pnpm
```

Then this logs, came out

```
Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at C:\Users\<UserName>\.pnpm-store\2
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Packages: +1
+
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 0, downloaded 0
Resolving: total 1, reused 1, downloaded 0, done
ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\pnpm'
```

**What I want**
To understood what's the problem and what's the solution..

1. Can somebody explain what's happening here?
2. What are the solutions to use PNPM?
3. At first, when I launched the first command it works fine, I can call `pnpm --v` fine, however upon the second command it behaves like what I said above. Should I abandon the second command and use PNPM as it is?

Comment: If `npm i -g pnpm` successfully update pnpm then you may just use pnpm to update npm.

Comment: There's a way to make `pnpm i -g pnpm` work. Here's a solution described: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/928#issuecomment-349608103

Comment: @ZoltanKochan yeah I've just seen that a few days after I posted this, however I haven't tried it yet..

Comment: @ZoltanKochan just tried it, same thing above happened. I already allow editing to `nodejs` in `Program Files` and `npm` files in `AppData`.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same error using MINGW64 (or CMD). Then installed pnpm via Powershell and it worked.